# JavaScript Regex For Sentence Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am trying to write a regex to validate a normal sentence with no weird characters other than the basic ones you would see in a sentence (e.g: .,':<>... etc) and that is no longer than 512 characters. I am struggling to figure out how to do this, even after trying to look up the appropriate documentation for it.

The test code with the regex I have right now is below, however this does not work unless I remove all special characters:

```
const sentence = "This is a test sentence with some special characters ./<>'...";

if (/^[\w]{1,512}$/i.test(sentence)) {
    console.log("You provided a valid sentence.");
}
```

How do I make it so that this regex allows for basic sentence characters?

Also, are there any helpful tools that I can use to create regex's for JavaScript? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I now realize that I need to just add in all the characters that I want to allow, but now I am unsure how to do so without breaking syntax and including the ' and " characters.

```
const sentence = "This is a test sentence with some special characters ./<>'...";

if (/^[\w~!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:";\'<>?,./]{1,512}$/i.test(sentence)) {
    console.log("You provided a valid sentence.");
}
```

Comment: Include all "basic sentence characters" you want to permit in the character set?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I mean all general characters on a keyboard but no special weird unicode characters or anything like that.

Comment: Please define the "normal sentence", "weird characters" and "basic sentence characters" notions. Else, the task is not possible to solve.

Comment: Same thing - put them all in your character set, and your code should work as desired. You might want to use character code ranges to simplify things

Comment: Basically I mean any special character on a keyboard, and not any other unicode characters. @CertainPerformance How would I do that exactly?

Comment: What you are trying to do is **not a trivial task**. Tokenizing text into sentences involves many tricky corner cases. If you want to get a good result, you shouldn't try to re-invent the wheel and instead look into something like [this](https://github.com/GitbookIO/tokenize-english).

Comment: I suspect OP wants to just allow something like `[a-zA-Z0-9 .,?]{1, 512}` (plus whatever other is a "basic sentence character") but asks in a very roundabout and confusing way. Because an actual *sentence* is exceptionally hard to match via regex.

Comment: I apologize for making this sound complicated. I now realise that I just need to include all of the characters that I want to allow, so I have now added that to the regex however I am unsure how to incorporate the ' and " without breaking syntax. I have edited the original post with my new regex, but it is broken and I am unsure how to correct it.

Comment: You need to escape special characters like i.e. `?` in javascript with \ (and perhaps in the surrounding, like in java/.net additional `"`'s). A good tester I use is https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Chrᴉz Thank you for the information. That website was very helpful! Thank you to everyone who helped me, I managed to get it working as intended.

Comment: @Chrᴉz no, `?` loses its special meaning inside a character class. Almost everything does. The only characters you need to escape are dash (only if not in the end), backslash and closing square bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from others in the comments of my original post, I managed to get what I wanted with the following code:

```
const sentence = "This is a test sentence with some special characters ./<>'...";

if (/^[\w~!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:";\'<>?,.\/]{1,512}$/i.test(sentence)) {
    console.log("You provided a valid sentence.");
}
```

Thank you to those who helped me!